# Wpf TreeViewItem MouseLeftButtonUp binding error Unable to cast object 'System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

I am trying to have a clickable TreeViewItem.

xaml:

```
<TreeViewItem Header="Csv Logs"  MouseLeftButtonUp="{Binding Path=CsvLocationClick}"/>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public MouseButtonEventHandler CsvLocationClick
    { get { return OnCsvLocationClick; } }
```

But at runtime, I get the error:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Provide value on 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' threw an exception.' Line number '18' and line position '54'.'

Inner Exception
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'.
```

What does this error mean?  How is it fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind to `MouseLeftButtonUp`. It's an event to which you are expected to hook up an event handler:

```
 <TreeViewItem Header="Csv Logs"  MouseLeftButtonUp="TreeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
```

**Code behind:**

```
private void TreeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // handle event...
}
```